# Error in phonegap build .. for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to build my app for ios using phonegap build but I am getting this error
Error - A plugin in your app does not support the compulsory arm64 (64-bit support) architecture.

here are my plugins

```
io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite       
nl.x-services.plugins.toast     
org.apache.cordova.device       
org.apache.cordova.geolocation      
org.apache.cordova.network-information   
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator
```

please how can i get rid of that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in the post below.

*phonegap builds 32bit or 64bits*
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-builds-32bit-or-64bits

I quote the answer:

> The builds only support iOS 6.x or newer.

One of these three (3) plugins are not 64-bit

- io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite
- nl.x-services.plugins.toast
- uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator

Remove all three and add them back one at a time.

Best of Luck
Jesse